# Is there any mechanism to use between in json string in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm so younger and want to find data like from dat1 to date2 from a given table but I want to fetch values from the JSON string. please help me out. I'm not able to use this

Query:

```
select sum(amount) as total_val
from payment_table
where account_type='ACCOUNT' and
      transaction_type='DEBIT' and transaction_status='SUCCESS' and 
      json_extract_path_text(extra_data,'readerTime') between 1601793000 and 1601879399
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to use this"? Do you get an error?